# Ruby JSON schema draft-07 validation

Tags: ruby, jsonschema

I'd like to be able to do two things in some Ruby code:

1. Validate my schemas against the JSON schema draft-07 metaschemas, and
2. Validate my data against the schemas validated in (1).

A difficulty here is finding a Ruby library.

https://github.com/notEthan/jsi/ fails to read any schemas, even its own example on that page. I'd guess that it's because I'm using Ruby 3.1; it's fine with Ruby 2.7.5.

https://github.com/voxpupuli/json-schema is not fully maintained any more and only supports draft-04. Other than that it does what is required. I'm currently using this library, e.g.

```
test "schema validates against the standard" do
  metaschema = JSON::Validator.validator_for_name("draft4").metaschema
  assert_equal JSON::Validator.validate(metaschema, @schema), true
end
```

https://github.com/davishmcclurg/json_schemer doesn't include metaschema validation.

Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: These are the only two Ruby implmentations listed on the JSON Schema website. If you run into problems, it's best to file Issues on the appropriate repo if you haven't already.

Comment: I'm currently trying to answer the same question. I've got some leads, but haven't ironed out a solution just yet. If you're still working on this, I'd love to connect.

Comment: In the end I forked the voxpupuli/json-schema code and made a few edits so it would (apparently) validate against draft-06. At present it appears as if some updates have been made upstream which may fix things, so I'll take a look again.